# GridBagLayout, disappearing JList

Tags: java, layout, gridbaglayout

I wrote simple java application. One window (JFrame ramka) containing 3 elements: JButton, JComboBox and container (which contain JList).
I would like to rearrange positions of those elements, and it cause problems. I would like to use GridBagLayout, but when I do this, my container disappears(or it is 1px large -.-), also setSize works fine for JComboBox. And when I do not use any layout, container with JList is shown, but resizing JComboBox doesn't work, and everything is overlaping itself... generaly it looks like.. it doesn't look at all.

here come my question: how, and what layout use to reorganise positions of my compnents and JFrame?
i use NetBeans 7.2

```
package layouttest;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JList;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Layouttest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame ramka = new JFrame();
        //ramka.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 3));
        //ramka.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        String [] test = {"cos", "cos2", "cos3", "cos4", "cos5", "cos6", "cos7", "cos8", "cos9","cos10", "cos11", "cos12"};
        ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
        myList.add("cos");
        myList.add("cos2");
        myList.add("cos3");
        myList.add("cos4");
        myList.add("cos5");
        myList.add("cos6");
        myList.add("cos7");
        myList.add("cos8");
        myList.add("cos9");
        myList.add("cos10");

        GridBagConstraints ogranicznik = new GridBagConstraints();
        ogranicznik.insets = new Insets(5, 10, 5, 5);
        ogranicznik.gridx = 0;
        ogranicznik.gridy = 0; 

        Container c = new Container();
        ramka.setSize(500, 500);
        c.setSize(100,100);

        JList lista = new JList(myList.toArray());
        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(lista);
        JTextField txt = new JTextField("cos");
        c.add(sp);

        sp.setSize(100,100);
        lista.setSize(100, 100);
        ramka.add(c);
        ramka.add(txt);

        String[] dropBoxList = {"uno", "due", "tre"};
        final JComboBox listaRozwijalna = new JComboBox(dropBoxList);

        listaRozwijalna.setPrototypeDisplayValue("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"); 
        listaRozwijalna.revalidate();
        listaRozwijalna.repaint();
        ramka.add(listaRozwijalna);

        c.revalidate();
        c.repaint();
        ramka.revalidate();
        ramka.setVisible(true);
        ramka.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        // TODO code application logic here
    }
}
```

@EDIT
i discovered that java has problem with showing container while using layout models...

Comment: When you add the component in scrollpane, you will also need to set the view port.

you can use

sp.setViewPortView(Component) method and try.

Comment: Why put a JList in a scrollpane?

Comment: In my understanding JList by default don't have scrollPane with it. So, to augment the JList and allow scrolling we need to add JList to ScrollPane.

Comment: @pratikch -> you say that I should made sp.setViewportView(lista)? if yes - it doesn't change anytnig ;p

Comment: You never set everything correctly for gridbaglayout to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

I've rearranged your code and added in a GridBagLayout.  I had to guess how you wanted to arrange your components.

1. Always make sure that your Swing components are on the Event Dispatch thread.  That's what the main method does.
2. Separate your GUI components from your data definitions.  This makes verifying your GUI components easier.
3. Define your GUI components in the order that they are placed on the main JPanel.
4. Always define a main JPanel.  This gives you more flexibility in which layout manager(s) you want to use to define your GUI.
5. Always use one or more layout managers.

Here's my version of your code.

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Layouttest implements Runnable {

    protected Insets    ogranicznik = new Insets(5, 10, 5, 5);

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame ramka = new JFrame();

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        JTextField txt = new JTextField("cos");

        addComponent(panel, txt, 0, 0, 1, 1, ogranicznik,
                GridBagConstraints.LINE_START, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        JComboBox listaRozwijalna = new JComboBox(setDropBoxValues());

        addComponent(panel, listaRozwijalna, 1, 0, 1, 1, ogranicznik,
                GridBagConstraints.LINE_START, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        JList lista = new JList(setListValues());
        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(lista);

        addComponent(panel, sp, 0, 1, 1, 1, ogranicznik,
                GridBagConstraints.LINE_START, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        ramka.add(panel);
        ramka.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        // ramka.setSize(500, 500);
        ramka.pack();
        ramka.setVisible(true);
    }

    protected void addComponent(Container container, Component component,
            int gridx, int gridy, int gridwidth, int gridheight, Insets insets,
            int anchor, int fill) {
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints(gridx, gridy,
                gridwidth, gridheight, 1.0D, 1.0D, anchor, fill, insets, 0, 0);
        container.add(component, gbc);
    }

    protected String[] setListValues() {
        String[] test = { "cos", "cos2", "cos3", "cos4", "cos5", "cos6",
                "cos7", "cos8", "cos9", "cos10", "cos11", "cos12" };
        return test;
    }

    protected String[] setDropBoxValues() {
        String[] dropBoxList = { "uno", "due", "tre" };
        return dropBoxList;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Layouttest());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i did it in quite other way... i just ommited containers...

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package layouttest;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JList;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


/**
 *
 * @author kula
 */
public class Layouttest {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame ramka = new JFrame();
       //ramka.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 3));
        ramka.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        String [] test = {"cos", "cos2", "cos3", "cos4", "cos5", "cos6", "cos7", "cos8", "cos9","cos10", "cos11", "cos12"};
        ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
        myList.add("cos");
        myList.add("cos2");
        myList.add("cos3");
        myList.add("cos4");
        myList.add("cos5");
        myList.add("cos6");
        myList.add("cos7");
        myList.add("cos8");
        myList.add("cos9");
        myList.add("cos10");

        GridBagConstraints ogranicznik = new GridBagConstraints();
//ogranicznik.insets = new Insets(5, 10, 5, 5);
ogranicznik.gridx = 0;
ogranicznik.gridy = 2; 

        Container c = new Container();
        ramka.setSize(500, 500);
   // c.setSize(100,100);

    final JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane();
    JList lista = new JList(myList.toArray());

   sp.getViewport().add(lista);//!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

    //sp.removeAll();

    //c.add(sp);
   //sp.setViewportView(lista);
  // sp.setSize(100,100);
   //lista.setSize(100, 100);
    ramka.add(sp);




    String[] dropBoxList = {"uno", "due", "tre"};
    final JComboBox listaRozwijalna = new JComboBox(dropBoxList);


   /* listaRozwijalna.setPrototypeDisplayValue("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"); 
    listaRozwijalna.revalidate();
    listaRozwijalna.repaint();*/
   // ramka.add(listaRozwijalna);


    c.revalidate();
    c.repaint();
    ramka.revalidate();


    ramka.setVisible(true);
    ramka.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        // TODO code application logic here
    }
}
```